# Devices gets deleted from installation while sending push notification in Strongloop

Tags: javascript, strongloop

I am new to strongloop and I implemented push notification for android.

Everything was working fine for sometime then devices started disappearing from installation collection in database while sending notification. I don't have any idea why this is happening, please help me out on this.

What are all the scenarios in which this can happen?

My pushService code used for sending notification:

```js
 exports.sendPush = function (appObject,deviceId,type,userId,incomingMessage)  {
      var PushModel = appObject.models.push;
      var androidNotification = appObject.models.notification;

      // to avoid event emitter memory leak
      pushModel.removeAllListeners('error'); 

      var note = new androidNotification({
        message: incomingMessage,
        deviceId: deviceId,
        type: type
      });

      pushModel.notifyByQuery({userId: userId,deviceType:"android"}, note, function(err) {
             if(err)
              {
                console.log('android : pushing notification failed to %j', userId);
              }
             else
             {
                console.log('android : pushing notification to %j', userId);
                console.log('android note : ',note);
             }
         });

      pushModel.on('error', function (err) {
         console.error('Push Notification error: ', err.stack);
      });
};
```

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: Any solution on that one @mnesarco ?

Comment: I am sorry @ilir-aga I am not using StrongLoop anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the issue:

When APNs or GCM provider rises a devicesGone-event, the corresponding installation is deleted. See push-manager.js of loopback-component-push package.

In my case the application was set to production=false, but was in production mode (TestFlight).

To stop this approach, the destroyAll of your installation model must be hooked and overwritten:

See here, my Installation-model is called Participanz
http://pastebin.com/aaed22dZ